# Flutter: Skipped 48 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing above issue while trying to perform update in DB when user closes app. Update to DB works fine if I click **Home** button to close the app, the update function is working fine but if I click **device back button on physical device** to close the app then I get application may be doing too much work on main thread.

I am unable to debug the issue. Can someone please help.

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // App is in the background or closed, make the HTTP request to update
      // view counts for the series.
      updateViewCountsInFirestore();
    }
  }
```

On debugging I can see, this function (updateViewCountsInFirestore) is getting called but requesting firestore to update DB is creating this issue.